# How to add image to the database via web api c# from form data of postman

Tags: asp.net-web-api, model-view-controller, postman, multipartform-data

I am trying to add an image to a database via a c# web api. However, when I call the API using Postman I get the error:

> Object must implement IConvertible.

My controller code:

```cs
    // POST: api/Projects
        [ResponseType(typeof(Project))]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostProject(Project project)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);

            project.Name = HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["Name"];
            project.Description = HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["Description"];
            foreach (string file in HttpContext.Current.Request.Files)
            {
                var postedFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[2];
                string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(postedFile.FileName);
                string extension = Path.GetExtension(postedFile.FileName);
                fileName = fileName + DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssfff") + extension;
                project.Image1 = fileName;
                fileName = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Image/"), fileName);
                postedFile.SaveAs(fileName);
            }
            project.Status = 1;

            db.Projects.Add(project);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = project.ProjectID }, project);
        }
```

My database table:

[image: this is how my table looks like]

Model:

[image: this is how my model looks like]

And I am getting error like this in Postman:

[image: Postman error]